# Open websites in new tabs but don't focus them (with python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to open 10 websites for reading in other tabs later. Therefore I don't want to focus them. The focus should remain on the actual tab. But when I use

```
url = "www.stackoverflow.com"
webbrowser.open(url, new=0)
```

the programm switches to the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html):

```
webbrowser.open(url, [new=0, [autoraise=True]])
```

If `autoraise=True`, the window is raised if possible. What you're looking for is to set `autoraise=False` so that the window stays in the background.

Note: that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the setting of this variable. Check what window manager you're calling. And accordingly modify this variable.

Comment: I tried this before, but this is also not working under Linux and Chromium-Browser.